# How do I mock an Angular controller when I compile the directive?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have the following Angular code...

```
<!-- Directive Template -->
<div style="display:hidden" ng-if="ctrl.test()">
...
// Controller
...
this.test = function() {
    return false;
}
```

Now I need to mock `ctrl.test` so I can test that the DOM is rendered properly when true (this isn't the real code just for demo that is why it returns false). I try the following test...

```
    beforeEach(module('mod'));
    var $controller, $scope, $httpBackend, $rootScope, $compile;
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_, _$compile_){
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        $controller = _$controller_(ImpactFormController, {
            $scope: $scope
        });
        $compile = _$compile_;
    }));
    describe("Form Functionality", function(){
        it("Submitting saves the form properly", function() {
            //TODO Should we check the response this seems uness.
            var compiled = $compile('<my-d></my-d>')($rootScope);
            $rootScope.$digest();
            var controller = compiled.controller('my-d');
            spyOn(controller, "test").and.returnValue(true);
            $rootScope.$digest();
            console.log(JSON.stringify(controller.test()));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(compiled[0].innerHTML));
        });

    })
```

The console that is calling the method returns true as expected. However, the DOM is never updated. After the mock I would expect something like this...

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div style="display:hidden"> </div> <!-- ng-if -->
</div>
```

I also tried...

```
// Trying to recompile
spyOn(controller, "test").and.returnValue(true);
$rootScope.$digest();
var recompiled = $compile(elem)($rootScope);
console.log(JSON.stringify(recompiled[0].innerHTML));
```

Still nothing.

Comment: What exactly would you like to test in your directive?

Comment: Tried to add more detail, let me know if that helps.

Comment: I can see the point about it is just testing ng-if let me go back and see if it is possible to ignore this test. But the question still stands in case I cannot (plus I am just interested) :-)

Comment: The point of a unit test is to test what your directive (javascript code) does. You don't need to test what ngIf does. That's covered by the angular team unit tests. I'd rather test that your method test returns the value that you expect.

Comment: Ok so here is the deal. This was an existing test we are trying to fix and although I agree with you that it may be a philosophical question I want to make that a sidebar.

After talking to someone about the real failing test, it appears that this is a side effect issue. Without this DOM appearing, other assertions later on will fail. 

I would like to know if there is a way to mock out a function that is used to fill in an ng-if.

Comment: Thanks now I know what the definition of a unit test is but that doesn't answer this question, unless the answer is you can't and then a reference would suffice.